# Unexpected order of execution - GUI only updates after download is completed

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside

I have developed a GUI with pyside and it is executing a command after a button is pressed. The first command in the function that is called will update the status to "Downloading..." in the text_terminal. The second command will start the actual download (an SQL query which is performed via Pandas and cx_Oracle).

The odd thing is, that the text_terminal is only updated with the after the download is completed. Any suggestions what can be causing this?

```
ui.text_terminal.append("Downloading....")
self.df = dbrs.retrieve(date)
```

Comment: GUI code usually has an event loop running to process updates.

Comment: How can I make sure that 'loop' has completed the latest task before something else is executed?

Comment: What's probably happening is the event loop is not running while you do your download.  If you want a GUI to do anything, then long-running tasks need to be done by a separate thread.

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects#Blocking_the_event_loop

Answer (score 2):

The GUI doesn't update until the redraw events are processed.  Those are typically done at the beginning of an event loop.  If your application is busy running python code, it won't proceed to the next cycle of the event loop until that code is finished running.  The proper way is to push long-running operations into a separate thread, so that it doesn't hold up the main GUI thread and the event loop can keep processing GUI update events, but there are ways to hack around it.

You can simply tell the application to process the redraw events.

```
ui.text_terminal.append("Downloading....")
QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
self.df = dbrs.retrieve(date)
```

Call this before your `retrieve` function and it should force an update of the GUI.

The other way is to simply push the operation to the next event loop cycle, which means there will be at least 1 redraw before it executes.  You can do this with a singleshot `QTimer`.  This breaks up the flow of your function, so it only really makes sense if you aren't doing anything else after the download.

```
def do_retrieve(self, date):
    self.df = dbrs.retrieve(date)

ui.text_terminal.append("Downloading....")
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1, lambda: self.do_retrieve(date))
```

Comment: the download still bocks the UI, just a moment later. "so it only really makes sense if you aren't doing anything else after the download." - one could move that "anything else" into do_retrieve(). The main problem here is to use a synchronous API for the download though, the proper solution would be to start the retrieval asynchronously and have a callback called when its done.